# Spring boot + batch: JpaItemWriter does not update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, batch-file, spring-boot

I have a project with spring-boot which uses batch. The reading is working fine (i read from a CSV file) and mapping to my POJO also works (also Inserts into the DB, but not updates...).

But here comes the problem:
I use `JpaItemWriter` and an Entity with an Auto-generated ID (`long` value). When I don't set that Id in the Bean, it will be an insert with the next value (this works like it should).

But the problem is, sometimes I don't need an insert, but rather an update. When I set the Id to the same Id like an existing entry in database (H2 - saved to file) it either makes another Insert or I get a primary key violation.

I also tried `@DynamicUpdate(true)` and `@SelectBeforeUpdate(true)` at the Entity class, but it doesn't work.
The long Id key, has also the `@Id` declaration.

How can I force updates or load the database in my `PersistenceContext`?

And the `ItemReader` reads a POJO, `MyProcessor` converts the POJO to the Bean (which has more fields, that are just in the DB and not in the CSV file) and returns either `null` if nothing is to do or the Bean (either with no Id set = Insert, or with an old Id = which I hoped would be an update).

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are just referring to the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I have to return the Item (Bean) from the DB/Repo-itself and not a new created one with the same Id.

Then I get an Update.